# DLL function calling in Excel Macro

Tags: dll, excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8DSN.png)When I execut the Code when the function of DLL calls it give error 429 "Active X component did not Create Object"...

Here i depicted the VBA code which i use.

I also include the libraries..

1. Sample.tlb
2. Microsoft Active X 6.0 Object Library
3. 'Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object'

I run this code in MS Office 2010 64 bit and 64 bit Operating System.

Comment: Can you place the code in the question not as an image

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Run-time-error-429-Activex-Component-can-039-t-create-object-yJSzKSwa.html) might help. It looks like your Activex component must yet be registered.